# Restore huge file from rdiff-backup with few space on / - why does rdiff-backup use so much space on /?

Tags: rdiff-backup

I try to restore a 5GB file from a backup:

```
$ rdiff-backup -r 2012-01-26 /backup/path/to/file /restore/dir
Exception '[Errno 28] No space left on device' raised of class '<type 'exceptions.IOError'>':
```

Wenn I do so, I run out of space on `/`. I have 8GB free space on `/` and a lot more on the partion with the backups and on the one for the restore. Now I ran out of ideas. Well soon I should give `/` more space, but this is not something I can do *now*. Where does rdiff-backup put all these tmp data excactly? It doesn't seem to be /tmp!
How can I restore manually from the diff.gz-File?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem using `--tempdir`, see here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/9951/rdiff-backup-and-running-out-of-disk-space-something-weirds-going-on